# sfdisk partition size in bytes

Tags: bash, script

Kind of homework related so further reading is always appreciated!

Using sfdisk I have to specify the size of certain partitions in bytes.

For this I used

```
sfdisk -lub /dev/sdd
```

Which lists the units as sectors of 512b. Is there an option to only show the count of single bytes? I've been slightly cheating and taking the output and multiplying it for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

so you want to show how much bytes per partition, right? just use -l argument only, or if you want to know how exacty per partition just use -s argument. this is manpage for sfdisk http://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk